# Asp.net defalut style sheet edit/delete?

Tags: css, asp.net

I am creating a new asp.net web application.
Application contains a  default master page i.e site.master. 
That Master page has link to site .css that was the by default css attached.

link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"

I removed site.css from my project(exclude from project) but its functionality survive. How this is happening? Why the styles gets not deleted or removed?? 
I am Using IE11.

Comment: Empty your browser cache and do total refresh, <CTRL><F5>?

Comment: Check your location where you have project and check in Styles folder whether exist Site.css..

Comment: I have deleted style folder and css file but still showing default style. Please suggest how that happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exclude from Project is not good way to do this.
Remove that file completely then you will not have that file loaded.

after that remove reference from master page or anywhere you are giving it.
Do CTRL + SHIFT+ F for entire solution search and search for that file name. so remove that references if you find.

now about browser cache issue. remove browser cookies and history. Or you have one more option like open your website and load with b y pressing
CTRL + F5. it will load your website totally fresh and with new code completely.